# SQL query that returns first row value but subsequent values are left as null

Tags: sql

I have a Function that returns a table. I have a field in the table from a Left join that causes some of the results to be duplicated. 
This causes the Totals to be wrong. I need to display it this way as it is used in a CSV result for another application.

```
Job Number   |   Job Total    |   Supp Ref (from a Left joined Table)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
4556              101.60          I450666
4556              101.60          P500694
4557              67.70           I88950A
4558              83.15           595900339
4559              132.00          O9995044
4559              132.00          I554112
4559              132.00          33209A00
4559              132.00          669554


Create Function JobDetails
{
 ... <Bunch of Params>
...
@JobDate DateTime
}
Returns Table 
as 
Return

Select 
JOBNUMBER, 
JOBTOTAL, 
SUPPREF
from 
(Select J.JOBNO as JOBNUMBER, Sum(J.TOTAL) as JobTotal,
S.REFNO = SUPPREF
from
JOBS J Left Join
 JOBNOTES S on J.ID = S=JOBID
Where J.DATE >=@JobDate
Group by J.JOBNO, S.REFNO 
) as JobTotals
```

What I would like to see would be

```
Job Number   |   Job Total    |   Supp Ref (from a Left joined Table)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
4556              101.60          I450666
4556                              P500694
4557              67.70           I88950A
4558              83.15           595900339
4559              132.00          O9995044
4559                              I554112
4559                              33209A00
4559                              669554
```

I know it would be possible but I am not sure how to go about it. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what database language (and version) are you using?

Comment: If the join causes duplication, that means the join is wrong. You most likely have multiple fields that need to be joined on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your subquery is not necessary:

```
Select J.JOBNO as JOBNUMBER, Sum(J.TOTAL) as JobTotal,
       S.REFNO as SUPPREF
from JOBS J Left Join
     JOBNOTES S
     on J.ID = S.JOBID
Where J.DATE >= @JobDate
Group by J.JOBNO, S.REFNO
```

You can do what you want using window functions:

```
Select J.JOBNO as JOBNUMBER,
       (CASE WHEN row_number() over (partition by J.JOBNO order by S.REFNO) = 1
             THEN Sum(J.TOTAL)
        END) as JobTotal,
       S.REFNO as SUPPREF
from JOBS J Left Join
     JOBNOTES S
     on J.ID = S.JOBID
Where J.DATE >= @JobDate
Group by J.JOBNO, S.REFNO
```

Comment: AHHH. Had always wondered about the PARTITION by. Perfect answer. Thank you